# binding media keys to functions in vlc player

Tags: vlc-media-player

How do I bind the media keys (play pause stop forward .. ) to corresponding functions in the vlc player. For now, I have to use the spacebar for play/pause and stuff like that. I'd prefer being able to vlc even when it is minimized!

Comment: I tried assigning the hot keys in 'Tools->Preferences->Hot Keys', but of no avail

Comment: What does it have to do with programming ?

Comment: what system are you using? At my windows 7 desktop, the mediakey are working fine from the beginning on. I never had to bind them for the vlc player.

Answer (score 1):

I had some problem of the media keys not working with VLC v.1.1.11.

I had opened Windows Media Player and strangely, the media keys started working properly with the video played in it. I then closed Windows Media Player.

I opened a video with VLC player and Bing! It worked – just that I had the medium backward and medium forward not working. I went to the *Shortcuts* setting in *Preferences* in VLC, double click on *Global Setting* on these tasks, and when it says "press the key", I pressed the desired key in the remote control.

Still, the medium backward button was not working – and when FF is in focus it will open the library – I searched for the shortcut for opening the library in FF, and it was <kbd>Crtl-Shift+B</kbd>

So I have configured the medium backward in the VLC hotkeys to <kbd>Crtl-Shift+B</kbd> – and strangely Firefox does not open the library with this shorcut anymore.

It seems when programs are installed they will sometimes steal the global shortcut functionality.

Answer (score 0):

checkout the python bindings: at the bottom of that file it lists how it binds files to certain events. http://wiki.videolan.org/Python_bindings